# Chi square independence test

Tags: education

How to work out chi square independence in the following table?

Below is the observed and expected data concerning 7 themes displayed in a newspaper over a period of 3 months. I understand how to work out chi square but not with this number of columns and rows. Thank you!

```
        May     June    July    Total           May     June    July    Total 
Gov     16      34      28      78      Gove    18.525  29.25   30.225  78
Mort    1       0       1       2       Mort    0.475   0.75    0.775   2
Damage  0       2       1       3       Damage  0.7125  1.125   1.1625  3
Recon   0       3       7       10      Recon   2.375   3.75    3.875   10
Relief  18      16      18      52      Relief  12.35   19.5    20.15   52
Health  0       0       2       2       Health  0.475   0.75    0.775   2
Survi   2       3       4       9       Survi   2.1375  3.375   3.4875  9
Other   1       2       1       4       Other   0.95    1.5     1.55    4
Total   38      60      62      160     Total   38      60      62      160
```

$$ \small \begin{array} {r|rrr|r||r|rrr|r}
obsrv.  & May & June & July & Total & expct. & May & June & July & Total \\
\hline
 Gov & 16 & 34 & 28 & 78 & Gove & 18.525 & 29.25 & 30.225 & 78 \\
 Mort & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & Mort & 0.475 & 0.75 & 0.775 & 2 \\
 Damage & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & Damage & 0.7125 & 1.125 & 1.1625 & 3 \\
 Recon & 0 & 3 & 7 & 10 & Recon & 2.375 & 3.75 & 3.875 & 10 \\
 Relief & 18 & 16 & 18 & 52 & Relief & 12.35 & 19.5 & 20.15 & 52 \\
 Health & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & Health & 0.475 & 0.75 & 0.775 & 2 \\
 Survi & 2 & 3 & 4 & 9 & Survi & 2.1375 & 3.375 & 3.4875 & 9 \\
 Other & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & Other & 0.95 & 1.5 & 1.55 & 4 \\
\hline
 Total & 38 & 60 & 62 & 160 & Total & 38 & 60 & 62 & 160 \\
 \end{array}
$$

Comment: Hi I've formatted your table as text and as LaTex. Hope this did not frustrate you... feel free to redo/delete if/what is convenient

Answer (score 1):

The test statistic would be
$$
\sum \frac{(\text{observed}-\text{expected})^2}{\text{expected}}.
$$
It should have a chi-square distribution with $(8-1)(3-1)=14$ degrees of freedom if the hypothesis of independence is true.  It it has an improbably large value, you reject the null hypothesis.